# Meaning of "save it was"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Few, indeed, were the folks that ever came this way, for it was in the loneliest
>   part of Barnisdale Forest. Besides, who had any right to come here **save it was**
>   the king's foresters keeping strict watch and ward over the king's deer?

This phrase confused me does it mean: consider?

Source: The Merry Adventure of Robin Hood

Comment: It's effectively an ***archaic*** usage. Everyone today would use ***unless*** (or ***except***, with some other syntactic tweaks), not ***save*** in such contexts.

Answer (score 2):

It is old fashioned and quaint.

"Save" means "except".  So the rhetorical question asks "Who had the right to enter the forest *except the king's foresters* keeping watch over the deer?"

The "it was" is odd and dated, but "it" refers the "a person who can enter the forest"

Comment: I don't think it's exactly that ***it was*** is "dated". It is if you simply substitute ***except*** for ***save*** (where we might say *except **for***), but there's nothing at all "odd" about ***... unless it was** [so-and-so].*